# Cypress 12.12.0 Can not get body element of an iframe while the code works in any other iframe

Tags: cypress

I have been stuck in typing card number inside an iframe field. The problem is when i get the content of the iframe, it return nothing.

The card input page shown as pop-up page after a button is clicked

I used Cypress 12.12.0

This is the simplified version of the iframe's HTML

```
<iframe name="iframe-name" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-xxxx" title="Secure card payment input frame" >
    #document
        <html>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <form>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
</iframe>
```

[The iframe full element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWPPC.png)

My code snippet to get the iframe's element and checking the element

```
cy.get('iframe[title="Secure card payment input frame"]', { timeout: 10000 })
.then(function($iframe) {
        cy.log($iframe)
        const $body = $iframe.contents()
        cy.log($body)
      })
```

The issues is the iframe log return the iframe element

[cy.log($iframe)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjxtd.png)

but the body log return nothing

[cy.log($body)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aI4g.png)

I used the similar code on the other iframe and it works. The other iframes are for rich-text area editor in the same page

The chrome security is disabled

Comment: It's not because I can't even access the body inside the iframe yet

Answer (score -1):

First query into the iframe as below and find the body. The use `cy.wrap()` to wrap the object and use `find` method to get the desired elements:

```
cy.wait(5000);
cy.get('iframe[title="Secure card payment input frame"]')
   .then(($iframe) = > {
        const $body = $iframe.contents().find("body");
        let element = cy.wrap($body);
         // for example if you want to find the input text field, usage as below:
            element.find('input[type="text"]).type("Some text");
      });
```

Comment: Does '$ele' = '$iframe'?? because i got error that $ele isn't defined yet.

If yes, I've tried this and the $body is still empty, making the wrap function return error because $body is 'undefined'

Comment: Yes, my bad, i have corrected that to $iframe

Comment: Ok, Can you please check, if there are more than 1 iframe in the DOM ?

Comment: Also please attach and expand iframe screenshot to the question

Comment: There are multiple iframe in the page, but the get-by-title locator return my target iframe. I have post the full iframe element.

Comment: Ok thanks. 
Can you add a wait before reaching the iframe function and see if there is any delay required for the loading the iframe contents. Pls see my answer above like wait adding

Comment: I've add the timer as you mentioned, and add additional timeout inside the find body so it become '.find("body", { timeout: 10000 })' but it still return empty